# How to center an image that is wider than the browser window (not a background image)

Tags: css, image, center

How can I centre a large image to the browser window, so that if it is wider than the window it will still be centred?

See: http://carolineelisa.com/rob/

I did not want to simply make the image a background image, as it changes dynamically to images of different sizes and I want to to be able to scroll down to see them at the correct heights.

However I am open to making it a background image if the height of the container div can change depending on the background image height?

I don't mind having a horizontal scrollbar, but would prefer not to.

Thanks!

Comment: you can do this with a container that is positioned absolute/fixed with a width and height of 100%.  background can then be set to `background-position: center center` I think?

Comment: Thanks @Joseph, this centres perfectly but I'm afraid there is no scrollbar for me to see the bottom half of the image.

Comment: hm... let me put an answer... might make things easier.

Comment: See my answer. (oh wow... I almost ended that sentance with a semicolon O_O).

Comment: I took the liberty of reconstructing your page to see if I couldn't fix the issue and it seems to have worked.  See my latest edit.

Comment: Thank you again for your patience @Joseph!  I had other styles interfering with my version.

Comment: Ah I see. Glad to help where I could. :)  It was really fun XD

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<div style="background:url(/path/to/image.png) center top; width:100%; overflow:hidden">
  <img src="/path/to/image.png" style="visibility: hidden;">
</div>
```

This... probably will get you where you want.

and the example: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/seepW/2/show/) [and source](http://fiddle.jshell.net/seepW/36/?123456)

## Edit

fixed it: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/seepW/7/show/) [and source](http://fiddle.jshell.net/seepW/7/)

Comment: Oh dear, just realised that the div keeps the height of the original invisible placeholder image after I dynamically change it. So I guess I will use javascript for this after all.

Comment: My bad, other styles were interfering with my version. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Nearly two years later, I was having a similar issue and wanted to solve it with only html/css (using javascript only to change between images).

Finally I had to resolve to a total of three elements to achieve always centered images (images both smaller and larger than the page/wrapping element).

The html construction

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="align"><img src="http://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/bulb-wallpaper.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

The css:

```css
div.container
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.container div.align
{
    position: relative;
    width: 10000px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -5000px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

While I don't really like having to work with insanely stretched elements, it seems super effective.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NjJ3G/3/

Comment: Rogier Spiekers answer is a good way! For dynamic use, take a look to jQuerys "wrap()"!

Comment: Much better solution. I had to tweak this a little bit because I actually wanted overflow-y to be visible, but this helped me out immensely. +1

Comment: Worked well. For printed page, add `body {margin: 0}` to make sure the image actually goes to the edge of the page.

Comment: Version with inline CSS: <div class="container" style="position: relative; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="align" style="position: relative; width: 10000px; left: 50%; margin: 0 0 0 -5000px; text-align: center;">
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/banner.jpg" />
</div>
</div>

Answer (score 3):

Best solution with an `img` tag of unknown dimensions is to :

```
.bg-fluid {
    position:absolute;
    left:-1000%;right:-1000%; // horizontal center
    top:-1000%; bottom:-1000%; // vertical center
    margin: auto;
}
```

you can also make it responsive with:

```
.bg-fluid-responsive {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

and the `img` tag:

```
<img class="bg-fluid bg-fluid-responsive" src"..."/>
```

no need for containers.

note: aspect ratio **will be** preserved.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, the best way to do it is with a background image. Since you're going to be using javascript to change the image, you can go ahead and add a little more to change the height as well. To do so, load the image into an invisible div (`style="position:absolute; top:-3000px; left:-3000px;"`) in addition to setting it as a background-image. You can then use javascript to get its height from the img tag inside the invisible div.